# How to convert Type to Class in C#

Tags: c#

I need to learn  how to convert type to Class in C#.

In my case, I have an double array object  but they are stored in object array.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values == null || values.Any(v => v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
        return false;
    var typeOfArray = values[0].GetType();
    var firstItem = (double)values[0];
    return values.Skip(1).Any(item => (double)item == firstItem);
}
```

I  want to make this generic implementation for  any type but equals(method and operator) 
doesn't work.
But if I convert type to class I think I can do what I want.

But I want to learn ideas and how should I do this operation or  How can I convert type object to Class to use it conversion operation?

Comment: *Which* equals method/operator doesn't work? What do you mean by "convert type to class"? Your question is very unclear at the moment. What are you actually trying to *achieve*?

Comment: Hi Jon, Normally in OOP perspective, Equals  should work but for double value  0.0 == 0.0 return false if I dont do this conversion...
But I can get type of object and use it for conversion I think It will work!. Cheers

Comment: Have you thought of generics <T> pattern. Can you explain exactly what you are doing in your code. What is the use of typeOfArray and targetType variables?

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: No, if you call `Equals` for boxed double values, 0.0 and 0.0 *will* return as equal. You do have to use `Equals` rather than `==`, but it will be fine. It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a  MultiValueConverter class. This class check first element is included in rest of array. In my case it simply using values[0].Equals(...)  or values[0] == ... doesn't work. But I tried to use casting it double (double)values[0]==(double)... it works. I cant understand why...

Comment: You're not converting anything in this method, all this does is verifying if the first element occurs more than once in the "values" array you pass in... Why isn't the return type bool ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to make this generic implementation for any type but equals(method and operator) doesn't work.

Three options;

1: use the `object.Equals(x,y)` method (this uses the virtual `Equals(x)` method, but avoids a null-ref problem)

```
object firstItem = values[0];
return values.Skip(1).Any(item => Equals(item,firstItem));
```

2: use `dynamic`, but realise this may impact performance:

```
dynamic firstItem = values[0];
return values.Skip(1).Any(item => (dynamic)item == firstItem);
```

3: use generics (here, `values` is a typed, `T[]`):

```
var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
T firstItem = values[0];
return values.Skip(1).Any(item => comparer.Equals(item,firstItem));
```

The nice thing about the generics option is that you avoid the need to box when it *is* a value-type (such as `double`).